# Formal linguistic term for a "prepositional object"?

Tags: translation

examples:

> (1) The book is on the desk.
>   (2) I went to my favorite cafe.
>   (3) This present is for her.

the prepositional phrases / 前置詞句{ぜんちしく}:

> (1) ... on the desk.
>   (2) ... to my favorite cafe.
>   (3) ... for her.

the prepositions / 前置詞{ぜんちし}:

> (1) on;
>   (2) to;
>   (3) for;

the prepositional objects:

> (1) desk;
>   (2) cafe;
>   (3) her;

What is the formal linguistic term for a **prepositional object** in Japanese?

My native speaker sources suggested "前置詞句の目的語" and "前置詞句の補語", but they admitted to being unsure.

Comment: [Eijiro](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=prepositional) suggests [前置詞]{ぜんちし}付{つ}き[目的語]{もくてきご}, FWIW.

Comment: A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="前置詞付き目的語") suggests that this term is in use.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi In use, but rare.

Comment: @snailboat for that matter, the English term is 初耳 for me. :)

Comment: Talking about the object (or complement) of a preposition is fairly common in English grammar.

Comment: I'm not sure I've ever heard the term "prepositional object" before.  The term I grew up with was "indirect object" instead.  US East Coast upbringing; maybe it's a geography thing?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Indirect objects are completely different:: "I gave Jim the map.":: "Jim" is the indirect object, and "map" is the direct object.

Comment: Indeed. As I was taught as a kid (wrong or right by today's standards, I know not), "indirect object" applies equally to "Jim" in the constructions "I gave Jim the map" and "I gave the map to Jim", "I did Jim a favor" and "I did a favor for Jim", etc.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I'm with you on that. Though there are many, I was just taught one rigid methodology for modeling English grammar. Like, I've heard the term "complement", but I've no clue about the grammar methodology that uses that term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard ''前置詞の目的語''. 
It means the partner of the prepositional, not a role in a sentence.

''前置詞の目的語'' can be used even when the prepositional phrase is not regarded as a kind of the object in the sentence.

> I'm waiting for *her.*
>   I made a cake for *my children* with *her.*
>   I'm interesting in *ethnic food*.

These words in italics are all ''前置詞の目的語''.

Comment: Actually, I just learned "前置詞の補語". Do you think "前置詞補語" sounds natural in a conversation? Would most Japanese know that 専門用語?

Comment: I also actually learned ''前置詞の目的語''. I think the term ''補語'' is less popular than ''目的語''. Now I googled both of them, it seemed ''前置詞の目的語'' is used mainly.

Comment: @david 前置詞の補語 is a more technically neutral term, but if you're talking about that of English, 前置詞の目的語 should be the best, for that's how it's taught.

Comment: @david Oh, and 前置詞補語 is NG. It'd mean an "preposition _as_ complement".